# Python lower() return "\u200b"

Tags: python, unicode, python-requests

I want request POST using [Requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) library.
but problem is in [get_adapter](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/master/requests/sessions.py#L718).

my url is "http://sample_domain.com/sample_endpoint".
but `if url.lower().startswith(prefix.lower())`  passed away my url is "\u200bhttp://sample_domain.com/sample_endpoint".

why `\u200b`? i can't pass this loop.
just return `InvalidSchema`.

Comment: Where did the `\u200b` come from? Did you enter this in your code, or did you retrieve it from a website? Please add a [mre] to allow us to understand the problem and help you. Since '\u200b' is the zero width space character, my best guess at this point is that you copy-pasted the URL from a website, and it included that character. You can't see it (because it's "zero width"), but it can be part of the text you copied. It's not supposed to be part of the URL.

Comment: @wovano omg... you saved me

Comment: @wovano i copied url other into code editor. sometimes i got `\u200b`.

Comment: I'll post this as an answer for future reference :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably copied the URL from a website. `\u200b` is the [zero-width space character](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm). You can't see it (because it's zero-width), but it may be part of the website. Sometimes it's used for formatting reasons.

In the string representation in Python it is represented in this form.

**Solution:** just make sure to select only the text, or make sure your code removes the character, because it's not part of the URL, so it won't work if you keep it in the string.